# Show alternate for ad blockers

Tags: html, flash, ads

I was recently testing the Amazon MP3 Widget on my site.  It was not appearing and I realized it was being blocked by my ad blocker plug-in that prevents cross site flash objects.  I want to know if there is a way to tell people that they are missing this content.  It seems like the ad blocker simply removes any embed code.  What can I do to tell people they might be missing something they actually want to see.  I'm hoping there's something similar to the no script tag, but I'm assuming its more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy the iframe source URL through your server with a redirect.

**Edit:** You can use alternative content (check out [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/)) to provide either:

1. a link which issues an ajax request to get the embed/object code; this might bypass the blocker since it the page was already open;
2. a piece of text or an image alerting the user to turn off the ad blocker, since he's missing content.

Comment: I don't really want to force the user to see the content.  Maybe just show them a text link where they can see the content.